# How to design a customized Search Engine?

Tags: c#, api, search-engine, web-crawler

I want to design my own search engine application, where all the results are displayed to the user on one single page (from Google/Bing etc) unlike Google where it is displayed on different pages.

Does there exist any such API's which can get me all those results?

PS. I am using C#, and considering the `IEnumerator` interface for this?

Comment: What specifically is the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to fetch data from different APIs (bing/google etc) and then display it to the user in one flow. Otherwise, crawling search engines is totally illegal.

For Google, you can go to Google Custom Search API or if you have products to search then Google Shopping API.

For Bing, there is a simple and straightforward API.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to be able to serve search results to users, then the APIs provided by search engines are probably the way to go. As already mentioned there's [Bing's Live Search API](http://www.bing.com/developers) (which I've not used but looks fine), and also [Google's Web Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/). 
Additionally, there's [Yahoo BOSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/) which I found very easy to use. However, it looks like BOSS is now a paid API - so depending on your budget/intention, it might not suit.

Google's Web Search API is now deprecated, but should still work for a small number of queries - it's the platform that tools like [this number of results counter](http://azich.org/google/) are built on. It's been replaced by the [Google Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) which depending on your needs may or may not work for you. I've not used it, but it looks fine, and is free for small numbers of queries.

The problem with crawling and then parsing search pages is that search engines regularly change the underlying html of the search result pages - so any screen scraping approach will be quite brittle. Additionally, the [terms of service](http://www.google.com.au/accounts/TOS) of most commercial search engines prohibit automated access - if you go ahead anyway they may well block your crawler. These two problems are probably why awesome third party parsing APIs don't really exist.

Answer (score 0):

check [NUTCH](http://nutch.apache.org/). Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Bing has an open api http://www.bing.com/developers

Google gives you an api then immediately takes it away.  http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/

The google api is deprecated and I think they have another one that is even more limited.  Once upon a time they had an API that was comparable to Bing's.

For the exact scenario you mentioned though, the best thing to do is first parse out the number of results, then keep iterating through the pages.  You also need to handle errors well because Google very often lies about the number of results it contains.

Answer (score 0):

i m working in same project.
`Generate sitemap`

```
 private void SubmitSitemap(string PortalName)
    {
        //PING SEARCH ENGINES TO LET THEM KNOW WE UPDATED OUR SITEMAP

        //resubmit to google

        System.Net.WebRequest reqGoogle = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://your path'" + PortalName + "'/sitemap.xml"));
        reqGoogle.GetResponse();

        //resubmit to ask

        System.Net.WebRequest reqAsk = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://submissions.ask.com/ping?sitemap=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://your path + "'/sitemap.xml"));
        reqAsk.GetResponse();

        //resubmit to yahoo

        System.Net.WebRequest reqYahoo = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://search.yahooapis.com/SiteExplorerService/V1/updateNotification?appid=YahooDemo&url=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://yourpath/sitemap.xml"));
        reqYahoo.GetResponse();

        //resubmit to bing

        System.Net.WebRequest reqBing = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.bing.com/webmaster/ping.aspx?siteMap=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://yourpath + "'/sitemap.xml"));
        reqBing.GetResponse();

    }
```

Generate `robots.txt` file and place it in your root directory.Friendly name and other issues are also imp for this purpose.